# Using tabmove in vimrc give E488 Trailing characters error

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use the tabmove command in a function in my vimrc file but whenever I do I get the error "E488: Trailing characters: tabm l:x". This is the code:

```
function! MoveTabPageLeft()
    let l:x = tabpagenr()
    if l:x == 0
    else
        let l:x = l:x - 1
        tabm l:x
    endif
endfunction
```

How do I get it to call tabm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run the command that changes dynamically depending on the
value of a variable.  To run a command formed at runtime by a Vim script, use
the `:execute` command.  `:execute` takes single string argument containing
the command to execute.  So, to fix the code change the line

```
tabm l:x
```

to

```
exe 'tabm ' . l:x
```

Comment: Thanks for the description of why/when I should use exe - that really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code if anyone needs it. It moves the current tab page left or right.

```
function! MoveTabPageLeft()
    let l:x = tabpagenr()
    if l:x == 0
    else
        let l:x = l:x - 2
        exe 'tabmove ' . l:x
    endif
endfunction

function! MoveTabPageRight()
    let l:x = tabpagenr()
    if l:x == 0
    else
        exe 'tabmove ' . l:x
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: You can simplify these functions to `sil! exe 'tabm ' . (tabpagenr()-2)` and `sil! exe 'tabm ' . tabpagenr()`, respectively.